# Sort MPMediaItem by album

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaitem

I have an "songs" NSMutableArray filled with all songs on the device:

```
    MPMediaQuery *everything = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];   
    NSArray *songCollections = [everything collections];

    songs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (MPMediaItemCollection *song in songCollections) {
        MPMediaItem *representativeItem = [song representativeItem];  
        [songs addObject:representativeItem];
    }
```

Is there a way to sort them by album? I have noticed that adding

```
   [everything setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingAlbum];
```

produces a strange result (it's just pushing in the array the first song for each album)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the albums and then iterate through them to populate a song array, resulting in the songs sorted with respect to the albums:

```
NSMutableArray *sortedSongs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
MPMediaQuery *albums = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
NSArray* albumObjects = [albums collections];
for(MPMediaItemCollection *album in albumObjects) {
    for(MPMediaItem *song in album.items) {
        [sortedSongs addObject:song];
    }
}

NSLog(@"sorted songs : %@", sortedSongs);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the above query retrieves the albums, and each of those albums will contain the songs, right? so now if you add songs from these albums to your mutable array, won't you get songs sorted by albums?

Comment: probably it's because I'm a objective-c n00b, but I don't know how to access and store the songs later using this approach

Comment: alright I've edited my answer, to include the code, to iterate through the albums and populate the sorted songs array.

Comment: Thank you A LOT! I didn't know the "item" method, it works! Thank you again :)